# Unable to fetch Image from parse server

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I have created a Parse server on aws , Where I am trying to upload image through android. I have successfully uploaded the image in parse server(As far as it shows the uploaded). But when I click to download the image from the parse dashboard.It shows connection refused, And when I try to extract the image In my android(That is through Android). The logs shows the same connection refused

**Then I have manually uploaded a image in parse server(As .PNG file), even then when I try to download the image it shows connection refused

**there is no error in parse server

**I have even uploaded a txt document manually in parse server and tried to download it as usual it shows connection refused

**other thing work fine..like username.etc

**download url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/files/myappID/f18457154b524453f5998621e18ccb7b_agera.jpg
```

my logs in android studio , while fetching the image

```
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 1337) from /127.0.0.1 (port 41676) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:288)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:193)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.084 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: ... 32 more
2020-07-22 10:28:13.085 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.085 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:275)
2020-07-22 10:28:13.085 29699-29699/com.example.instagram W/System.err: ... 42 more
2020-07-22 10:28:13.098 29699-29699/com.example.instagram I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.instagram, PackageName:com.example.instagram
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log shows that your android app is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 which is incorrect, You must instead specify the IP address of the server running the parse-server.

Comment: Experiencing the exact problem, please show us how to specify the IP Address of the Server running Parse-Server

Comment: yeah thankyou. Can you even help me out in specifying the IP Adress of the server running